# R glmer.nb : how building model with interaction between categorial variables

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, interaction

Before posting this, I made some research but I am very struggle with my modelling approach, so I will try to be clear in what I want to do with my data.
I want to apologize if my questions are close of other topics, but I did not find any answer to what I want to do in other posting.

I have a dataset concerning counting data in grid cells. Within each grid cell, categorial variables where extracted (substrates, 5 categories ; topographic features, 4 categories).

What I want to do is building a model in which my response variable is the counting data (called in the model “Nb_pt_nv”) for several individuals, according to the substrate (called “Substrate”) and the topographic structure (called “Bathy_topo”).

I am new with mixed effect model so maybe there are some points I didn’t well understand.

I already built models with glmer.nb to deal with the overdispersion and to add a random effect corresponding to my different individuals, as follow:

```
Mod1 <- glmer.nb(Nb_pt_nv ~ Substrate + (1|ID_bird), data = data).
Mod2 <- glmer.nb(Nb_fix ~ Bathy_topo + (1|ID_bird), data=data).
```

With those two models, I have the impact of each categories, but independently.

What I would like is to build a model with interaction between substrates and topographic structures, but keeping the effect of each category independently.
I did some tests, but I don’t understand the output.

I tried this model:

```
Mod3 <- glmer.nb(Nb_pt_nv ~ Substrate:Bathy_topo + (1|ID_bird), data = data)
```

The thing is that I obtain in the output the effect of all the interactions, but I don’t have the effect of each category independently:

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approxim tion) ['glmerMod']
 Family: Negative Binomial(2.4986)  ( log )
Formula: Nb_pt_nv ~ Substrate:Bathy_topo + (1 | ID_bird)
   Data: F1_CB_all

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  7926.9   8000.7  -3949.4   7898.9     1427 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.2629 -0.7275 -0.2739  0.3640  7.4995 

Random effects:
 Groups  Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 ID_bird (Intercept) 0.06609  0.2571  
Number of obs: 1441, groups:  ID_bird, 10

Fixed effects:
                            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                 2.54474    0.17982  14.151  < 2e-16 ***
Sub1:Topo_Shelf            -1.36434    0.18114  -7.532 5.00e-14 ***
Sub2:TopoShelf             -0.96808    0.18090  -5.351 8.73e-08 ***
Sub3:TopoShelf             -1.08011    0.16919  -6.384 1.72e-10 ***
Sub2:Topo_Shelf_break      -0.88011    0.62247  -1.414 0.157393    
Sub3:Topo_Shelf_break      -0.57702    0.23998  -2.404 0.016198 *  
Sub4:Topo_Slope            -0.56675    0.16678  -3.398 0.000678 ***
Sub1:Topo_Slope            -1.23023    0.87412  -1.407 0.159308    
Sub2:Topo_Slope            -0.76328    0.21249  -3.592 0.000328 ***
Sub3:Topo_Slope            -0.62372    0.16481  -3.785 0.000154 ***
Sub5:Topo_Slope            -0.58459    0.20093  -2.909 0.003620 ** 
Sub4:Topo_Abyss            -0.07263    0.26459  -0.275 0.783688
```

Then I tried:

```
Mod4 <- glmer.nb(Nb_pt_nv ~ Substrate * Bathy_topo + (1|ID_bird), data=data)
```

But this time, I don’t know what the intercept is and all the interactions do not appear in the output:

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: Negative Binomial(2.4986)  ( log )
Formula: Nb_fix ~ Bathy_topo * Substrate+ (1 | ID_bird)
   Data: F1_CB_all

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  7926.9   8000.7  -3949.4   7898.9     1427 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.2629 -0.7275 -0.2739  0.3640  7.4995 

Random effects:
 Groups  Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 ID_bird (Intercept) 0.06609  0.2571  
Number of obs: 1441, groups:  ID_bird, 10

Fixed effects:
                                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                        1.52160    0.10993  13.841  < 2e-16 ***
Topo_Shelf_break                   0.50309    0.18218   2.762  0.00575 ** 
Topo_Slope                         0.45639    0.05822   7.839 4.53e-15 ***
Topo_Abyss                         0.95051    0.23844   3.986 6.71e-05 ***
Sub1                              -0.34120    0.11644  -2.930  0.00339 ** 
Sub2                               0.05506    0.10928   0.504  0.61439    
Sub3                              -0.05697    0.05676  -1.004  0.31555    
Sub5                               0.07263    0.26456   0.275  0.78367    
Topo_Slope:Sub1                   -0.32229    0.86530  -0.372  0.70955    
Topo_Shelf_break:Sub2             -0.41511    0.64224  -0.646  0.51805    
Topo_Slope:Sub2                   -0.25159    0.17062  -1.475  0.14033    
Topo_Slope:Sub5                   -0.09048    0.29375  -0.308  0.75808
```

I can't figure out why all the interactions do not appear in the last model. Does someone could explain me why it removes some?

Moreover, is there a way to have a model allowing to test the effect of each categories, and then the effect of the interaction between them on my response variable?

Finally, I would like to do a post-hoc test to compare the categories between them. I tried on my models 1 and 2 the glht function, which works, but it didn't when I tried on the models with interactions. Is there another way?
s.

Comment: The first model doesn't make much sense because it only includes the interaction, and not the main effects. In the 2nd model, the intercept includes the "baseline" values of the categorical variables (those levels appear to be `TopoShelf` for `Bathy_topo` and `sub4` for `Substrate`, and that is why you don't see all levels of each variable in the main effects and interactions.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. So if I understand well, the second model calculate all the interactions and the main effect, but the output doesn't show them? What is the way to get the estimates of the other interation and main effects?
Or is there a way to add in the first model the main effects of each category? I tried Bathy_topo + Substrate + Bathy_topo:Substrate but it gave me the same results as for the second model (Substrate*Bathy_topo)... Maybe I misunderstood how to specify interactions.

Comment: You have specified the interaction correctly. I think you need to read up about how to interpret the output of models that include interactions. There are lots of questions and answers here on CV.